# Idris: issue with Ord/Num

Tags: idris

I have a very simple example, as a demonstration of how to use `case _ of` that does not type check and I am not able to understand what the issue is:

```
data ZeroOrSign = Zero | Pos | Neg

sign : Ord elem => elem -> ZeroOrSign
sign x = case compare x 0 of
            LT => Neg
            EQ => Zero
            GT => Pos
```

The function `compare` is defined in Prelude, `compare : Ord ty => ty -> ty -> Ordering` where `Ordering` is just `LT`, `EQ` and `GT`. The error I get is the following:

```
When checking right hand side of sign with expected type
        ZeroOrSign

When checking an application of function Prelude.Interfaces.compare:
        Ord elem is not a numeric type
```

If I try to define `sign : Num elem => elem -> ZeroOrSign` then of course this creates issues as idris cannot find a function `compare` defined for `Num` types.

I am puzzled, any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compare`'s type requires `x` is of the same type* as `0`, which you haven't specified. Try

```
sign : (Ord elem, Num elem) => elem -> ZeroOrSign
```

* or there are appropriate conversions. I don't quite understand how this works, but `Num` appears to suffice, perhaps due to `fromInteger` converting the `0` to be of type `elem`

Comment: Thanks this works. Do I understand correctly that `(Ord elem, Num elem) =>` constraints the type of `elem` to be both an ordinal and numerical?

Comment: exactly, see [the docs](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces)